# I got this error when I try to install the PyAudio module using 'pip install PyAudio'... What should I do now?

Tags: python, module

Collecting PyAudio
Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Using legacy setup.py install for PyAudio, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: PyAudio
Running setup.py install for PyAudio ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\python 3.8\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\spogm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wul1u7y7\PyAudio\setup.py'"'"'; __
file__='"'"'C:\Users\spogm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wul1u7y7\PyAudio\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"
'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\spogm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-m6e8jsq4\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-
managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python 3.8\Include\PyAudio'
cwd: C:\Users\spogm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wul1u7y7\PyAudio
Complete output (9 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win32-3.8
copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8
running build_ext
building '_portaudio' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python 3.8\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\spogm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wul
1u7y7\PyAudio\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\spogm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wul1u7y7\PyAudio\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.
read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\spogm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-m6e8jsq4\install-record.
txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python 3.8\Include\PyAudio' Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: The error that seems the most clear to me is "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/" have you tried that? Are you in a position where you can download Visual C++ 14 or are you looking for a workaround?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Fx0ipi2Q Pastebin of this with codeblock formatting. (I can't edit the question itself to put it in a code block because then it complains that the question is all code.)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows:

Go to: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)

Download the file and then go to its directory in the cmd and type:

For win 32 bit:

```
pip install PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl
```

For win 64 bit:

```
pip install PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl
```